# Nokia S40 custom header bar

Tags: java-me, lwuit, nokia-s40

I'm building a custom header bar for Nokia S40, in LWUIT.

I've found 2 issues.

My `Form` has a `BorderLayout` and I've added the header bar (`Container`) in the NORTH. This container doesn't fill the width of the `Form`, as the `CategoryBar` does. I try with `BoxLayout` but I get the same result. I want that my custom header bar looks like the native `CategoryBar`, full width and visible over the rest of the `Components`.

Second issue.

I set my app to full screen using `Display.getInstance().setForceFullScreen(true);` and I've lost all the back `Commands`of my app. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change "headers" color if you are using Nokia S40. The color will be follow the mobile phone color theme.
The only way is using full screen, and draw ourself the Headers.

Answer (score 0):

In my application it's work:

```
protected void createTitle(Form f) {
    Container titleContainer = f.getTitleArea();
titleContainer.removeAll();
titleContainer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
titleContainer.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, titleBarContainer);
titleContainer.addComponent(BorderLayout.EAST, labelLogo);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work. Are you using it in an S40 app with Nokia SDK 2.0?